# os.rename on windows raise WindowsError instead of OSError

Tags: python, exception, file-rename

Python documentation says [that](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.rename)

> os.rename(src, dst)
>
> ... **On Windows, if dst already exists, OSError will be raised even if it is a file** ...

However, for me it raises WindowsError. Is there a mistake in the documentation?

The second part of the question (more general, but inspired by the problem formulated above):

**UPD** I am sorry, the second part of the question was incorrect. WindowsError is indeed catched by `except OSError` as it should.

Comment: Subclasses should be caught by default. Can you post your exact code and exact error?

Comment: Show me the code where a `WindowsError` is not caught by `except OSError:` and I will show you a bug in python

Comment: I think it's quite likely a separate WindowsError is raised outside a `try` block.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since OSError is a superclass of WindowsError, just catch the *OSError*.

FWIW, the core devs are free to raise an exception more specific than the minimum promised by the docs.

Also, the following code works fine for me (Python2.7.2 running on WindowsXP):

```
try:
    raise os.rename('nonexisting_file', 'def')
except OSError:
    print 'caught'
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @RobWouters Sure it does.  The OP asked if the docs were in error when they say OSError is raised instead of WindowsError, and I replied that that is allowed.  The OP further asked what is the correct way to catch the exception, and I answered that he should just catch OSError.  With a later edit, I also demonstrated that the technique Py2.7.2 is working fine on WinXP.  The OP is likely having some other problems as well, but his asked questioned were answered.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have double-checked and it seems that there was a problem somewhere else. Now I can not reproduce that behavior.